# Change binding of element inside template

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have a DataGrid where different items in the row can be either editable or readonly.

If I had a single cell that needed to be make read only at will, I'd use something like

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
    <!-- the non-editing cell -->
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ReadonlyCellTemplate">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding UserName}" />
    </DataTemplate>

    <!-- the editing cell -->
    <DataTemplate x:Key="EditableCellTemplate">
        <TextBox Text="{Binding UserName}" />
    </DataTemplate>
</DataGrid.Resources>
```

And than I would apply that template to a column of my choice.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn CellTemplate="{StaticResource ReadonlyCellTemplate}" Header="User name">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <!-- the additional layer of content presenter -->
            <ContentPresenter x:Name="Presenter" Content="{Binding}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource ReadonlyCellTemplate}" />
            <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                <!-- dynamically switch the content template by IsEditable binding -->
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding CreationFieldsEditable}" Value="True">
                    <Setter TargetName="Presenter" Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource EditableCellTemplate}" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </DataTemplate.Triggers>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

I want to be able to change `{Binding UserName}` inside the template, so I can apply the template to different columns.

How do I do that?

Comment: If you mean changing of binding property, for instance instead of Text="{Binding UserName1}" to Text="{Binding UserName2}", I usualy do in these cases changing the element itself by data trigger.
If I understood conditions well I can give details for the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of

```
 <DataTemplate x:Key="EditableCellTemplate">
    <TextBox Text="{Binding UserName}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

you need to extend the template:

```
  <DataTemplate x:Key="t1">
        <TextBox Text="{Binding UserName1}" />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="t2">
        <TextBox Text="{Binding UserName2}" />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="EditableCellTemplate">
        <ContentPresenter x:Name="ctp" />

        <DataTemplate.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding MyProperty}"
                         Value="1">
                <Setter TargetName="ctp"
                        Property="ContentTemplate"
                        Value="{StaticResource t1}" />
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding MyProperty}"
                         Value="2">
                <Setter TargetName="ctp"
                        Property="ContentTemplate"
                        Value="{StaticResource t2}" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </DataTemplate.Triggers>
    </DataTemplate>
```

This should work if I understand your idea well.